# how to remove an item from ListView while getView()?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

during `getView()`

I set the layout to each item in the list.

However there are some items I want to remove from my `ArrayList` and also not draw in the list.

My code goes like:

```
getView() {

    if (condition a)
    {
        myArrayList.remove(currentIndex);
        return;
    }

    doMoreLayouting();
}
```

Is this the right way?

Does it do any hurt when you remove an item from the collection during list drawing?

Comment: i don't think it's a good place to remove data from your adapter. why do you need to do it here?

Comment: why are you not checking this condition before given data to adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it do any hurt when you remove an item from the collection during
>   list drawing?

Yes it will, the main problem is that first the item in the collection will get deleted but what if the item is already called by the `getView` and you are deleting it after it is drawn then there is your first problem it wont get **deleted**, because you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` to call the `getView` all over again to delete it from the listView.

Second is that what if each item in your list need to delete somewhere in your array then it will call an call `getView` again and again which is not wise in performance of you application.

I would recommend deleting it from the method of your adapter and make sure that you gather all the data  that needs to be delete and call `notifyDataSetChanged` only once for performance wise.